# Changing minimum password length for Azure AD cloud only accounts under Azure ADDS

Tags: azure, azure-policy, azure-ad-domain-services

I understand that password policies for cloud-only user accounts in Azure do not allow us to change the minimum length from 8 to 10 based on existing Microsoft documentation.  I also understand that this **would be** possible for accounts that are synced from an on-premise AD.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-sspr-policy#password-policies-that-only-apply-to-cloud-user-accounts).

We do not have an on premise AD to sync, but we are using Azure Active Directory Domain Services where those cloud-only user accounts are listed. Does the restriction regarding password minimum length still exist for cloud only user accounts even if using Azure Active Directory Domain Services?